# Backup Magento Theme

Tags: magento, themes, backup

I am making some changes to a purchased magento theme. Is there any simpler way to backup my work other than by copying the relevant folders inside app skin and media and their directory structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I'd answer this for anyone coming along - as far as i can make out the answer to the question is no, not really - unless I'm doing it the wrong way - ( and I think not ) then the best method of backing up a custom theme is to first compress the entire app, skin and media ( if relevant) directories into one archive file, move this and expand it in an empty directory, then carefully delete all the other theme folders, leaving just the files which you are using and the directory trees which you have created - this preserves any files you have in your custom theme and also the necessary directory structure. If anyone has a better method maybe they'd share it.

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend that you do is to have your purchased theme as your default theme, i.e. in the "default" folder under your package. You can then declare another theme, e.g. "custom", and copy the path/files to there that you wish to override. You just need to set the "Default" value to "custom" in Admin > System > Configuration > Design > Theme.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm not sure if that helps me much. Do you mean that doing it this way I'd only have a few files; because even if I only have a few files I believe I still have to backup the relatively complex directory structure along with those files or else someone would have to be figuring out where the files go during a restore. I suppose I might do that if it was the only option but I was hoping to have something a bit more user friendly to give to the client as a backup.

Comment: Of course you need only preserve the file structure of the theme itself as a backup, but what I've outlined above should serve both as an in-place backup AND a best-practice approach to theming. The idea is that you keep an untouched copy of the theme under app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/default and skin/frontend/PACKAGE/default and do modifications in app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/custom and skin/frontend/PACKAGE/custom. This is an appropriate use of Magento's design fallback mechanism. Hope that clears things up a bit.

Comment: Thanks Ben but I think you must misunderstand my question and are thinking that I am asking about backing up the purchased theme before I work on it or something; I am asking about backing up "my work" - IE the changes that i am making to the purchased theme ( the contents of app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/custom and skin/frontend/PACKAGE/custom..... and also a media folder ) The problem is that for every file that I replace in the new theme I have a complex directory strucure ( i think the purchased theme had 40 folders so my custom theme has a similar structure).Hope this clarifies the question